# RestKit: Mapping nested json to one entity object

Tags: ios, json, mapping, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a nested json structure as below:

```
{
    "receiver-id":123456,
    "rewards": [
       {
        "content": "reward text 1",
        "reward-code": "456ABC",
        "reward-Id": "234"
      },
      {
        "content": "reward text 2",
        "reward-code": "012ABC",
        "reward-Id": "567"
       }
   ]
}
```

I have an entity object as follows that I wish to map the above json to directly:

```
@interface Reward: NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * receiverID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * content;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * rewardCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * rewardID;
```

How can I get the above json structure mapped directly to the above `Reward` entity? I do not want to have a collection or another entity just to store the `rewards` content from the json. I just want each `rewards` collection to be stored as a separate row in the `Reward` entity along with the corresponding high level `receiverID` property.

I tried the below mapping, but only the `receiverID` is being mapped. What am I doing wrong? How can I get access to the `rewards` array elements in this context?

```
_rewardsMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Reward" inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
_rewardsMapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
_rewardsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"rewardID" ];
[_rewardsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"receiver-id":@"receiverID",
    @"(rewards).content": @"content",
    @"(rewards).reward-code": @"rewardCode",
    @"(rewards).reward-id": @"rewardID"
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do what you want. The structure of your JSON would lead towards one object to hold the `receiver-id` and a relationship to a number of `Reward` instances. This is also how Core Data would prefer to store the data.

What you currently have is a mapping made up of a number of different features to support completely different JSON to that which you're receiving. You either need to:

1. Modify the source JSON to embed the `receiver-id` into each item in the array
2. Create a mapping for the 'container' and add a relationship to your `rewardsMapping` (and fix that mapping)
3. Map everything into a dictionary containing a couple of keys, one of which holds and array of other dictionaries, then post process that into your Core Data store